# Validate XML against XSD with SAXParser results in error

Tags: java, xml, xsd, validation

I have an XML file and a XSD file, I want to validate the XML against the XSD.

But I keep getting the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document '/connector/connector.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I printed the `canonical path` to make sure I was trying to use to right file. But it wont work.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <Content>
<commandLine>
<commandCode>A1</commandCode>
<marks><mark><code>mail</code><value>test@test.com</value></mark></marks>
<customerID>1</customerID>
<MessageType>2</MessageType>
</commandLine>
<Antwoordregel></Antwoordregel>
</Content>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Message" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="Content">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="commandLine" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:element name="commandCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="marks" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence >
                                        <xs:element name="mark" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence >                                                             
                                                    <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>                                                                
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>   
                            <xs:element name="customerID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="MessageType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Antwoordregel" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:element name="resultCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="statusInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="transactionInfo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The code I am using to validate:

```
static boolean validateAgainstXSD(String xml){
        try{
            File xsd = new File("connector/connector.xsd");
            System.out.println(xsd.getCanonicalPath());
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource("/connector/connector.xsd"));

            System.out.println(schema.toString());
            Validator validator  = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
            return true;
        }catch(Exception exe){
            exe.printStackTrace();
        return false;
        }
    }
```

It will always return false. I tried to validate the XML with the XSD with an online tool, which can be found here: [www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation). This validator returns:

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 2, 122: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 122; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xs:schema'.
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the 2nd line from XML File

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

The correct XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
    <commandLine>
        <commandCode>A1</commandCode>
        <marks><mark><code>mail</code><value>test@test.com</value></mark></marks>
        <customerID>1</customerID>
        <MessageType>2</MessageType>
    </commandLine>
    <Antwoordregel></Antwoordregel>
</Content>
```

Solution :

Please check the folder structure and run it again.

The Source Code :

```
package com.shashi.mpoole;


import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

public class XMLValid {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(validateAgainstXSD(new File("connector/connector.xml")))
        {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
    }



    static boolean validateAgainstXSD(File xml){
        try{

            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource("connector/connector.xsd"));

            Validator validator  = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
            return true;
        }catch(Exception exe){
            exe.printStackTrace();
        return false;
        }
    }

}
```

The Folder Structure

```
-----Project

    ------------- src

                  -------------XMLValid.java

    ------------- connector

                  -------------connector.xsd

                  -------------connector.xml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It validates now using the website. But I am still getting the same SAXParseException in Java: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document '/connector/connector.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.` Do you know what is causing this maybe? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks once again, tried implementing it in my code. But I still can't get it to work. Got a `MalformedURLException no protocol`. So I've changed the file path to `file://connector/connector.xsd but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you check the folder structure

Comment: Yes I placed all the files in the same structure as in your post, the exact exception I get is: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: connector/connector.xsd`

Comment: I did, I don't get it anymore >.<. I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you make change in XML. And Please try to create new project with the folder strucure..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I made some changes to the XML since the original one is too big and contains things I don't want to become public. I've made a new project, I am still getting the same error, scrolled down in the stacktrace to find: `java.io.FileNotFoundException /home/user/Desktop/Version 1/XMLParser/connector/connector.xsd (No such file or directory)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23096/discussion-between-jef-and-shashi-bhushan)

Comment: To handle errors in exact, please follow the [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0669.html)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this type of problem by changing the XSD which had a namespace prefix of "**xs:**" and search/replacing all instances to be "**xsd:**" instead (and also the xmlns:xsd= definition). Then I hosted this XSD on an internal server, pointed there in my schemaLocation attribute in the XML, and everything worked.

I tried this because of the precisely worded error:

- 3) the root element of the document is not **<xsd:schema>**.

I know, I know, this should not have worked, but it did. The external XSD which didn't work for me without translation is http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd

I'm not sure if this is a bug within SAX or Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to validate your XSD,
this one is the proper standard to avoid the exception what you get
(this one is full proof code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Message" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">

    <xs:element name="commandCode"  type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="code"  type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="customerID" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="MessageType" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="resultCode" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="transactionInfo" type="xs:string" />

<xs:element name="mark" >
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="code" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="marks" >
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="mark" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
         <!--End element Mark -->
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element> 
<xs:element name="commandLine">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element ref="commandCode"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="marks" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="customerID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="MessageType"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="statusInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="transactionInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Antwoordregel" >
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element ref="resultCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="statusInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>  
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- First Content Document Element -->
<xs:element name="Content">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="commandLine" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element ref="Antwoordregel" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```